# About rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, trace

> Let $A \in M_{6}(\mathbb{R})$ and $A^{3}-2 A^{2}-15 A=0$. If $\operatorname{tr}(A)=4,$ find $\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

---

How we can solve this?  I think we have  $x(x^2-2x-15)=0$ so $x=-3 ,0, 5$ so eigenvalues of $A$ are $3,5,0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note the following:

- Because $A^3 - 2A^2 - 15A = 0$, the eigenvalues of $A$ must be solutions to
  $$ 
  x^3 - 2x^2 - 15x = 0 \implies x(x+3)(x-5) = 0.
  $$
  However, we cannot conclude from this that each such solution is an eigenvalue. Because this polynomial has no repeated factors, $A$ must be diagonalizable.
- Note that $6 - \operatorname{rank}(A) = \dim \ker(A)$, where $\ker(A)$ denotes the kernel (AKA nullspace) of $A$. Note that $\ker(A)$ is the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $0$. For a diagonalizable matrix, the dimension of this eigenspace is equal to the (algebraic) multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$.
- The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues (up to algebraic multiplicity).

---

If $m$ is the multiplicity of eigenvalue $-3$ and $n$ is the multiplicity of eigenvalue $5$, then the trace of $A$ is $-3m + 5n$. We need to find non-negative integers $m,n$ for which $-3m + 5n = 4$ and $m + n \leq 6$.

Once we have done this, we find that the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is $6 - m - n$, and we can find the rank accordingly.

Comment: I can't understand your hint . what is rank of $A$ ?$ 2 ,3,4,5$ ?

Comment: @amirbahadory I've clarified things a bit, see my latest edit.

Comment: so $m=n=2$ and $rank(A)=4$ .

Comment: why $A$ must be diagonalizable ?

Comment: @amirbahadory That is exactly correct. $A$ must be diagonalizable because the polynomial $p(x) = x(x + 3)(x - 5)$ satisfies $p(A) = 0$, which means that the minimal polynomiial of $A$ divides $p(x)$, which means that the minimal polynomial of $A$ has no repeated factors. A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated factors.

Answer (score 0):

Given, $A$ satisfy the polynomial $x(x+3)(x-5)$.

Must remember, $A$ satisfy it's own minimal polynomial.
Suppose, $p(x)$ is minimal polynomial of $A$.

So, $A$ can satisfy the polynomial $p(x)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ is some other polynomial.

So, we can take minimal polynomial of $A$ as in $7$ ways.
So, $p(x)$ can be $(x)$ or $(x-5)$ or $(x+3)$ or $x(x+3)$ or $x(x-5)$ or $(x+3)(x-5)$ or $x(x+3)(x-5)$.

Clearly, for each case, $A$ must be diagonalizable,as each factor in minimal polynomial of $A$ appear only with degree $1$.

For the case , when $p(x)=x$, then $A$ is null matrix, so, rank($A$)=0.

For the case , when $p(x)=x-5 $, then $A=diag(5,5,5,5,5,5)$
So, rank is $6$

For the case , when $p(x)=x+3 $ ,then $A=diag(-3,-3,-3,-3,-3,-3)$ ,so ,rank is $6$.

For the case , when $p(x)=x(x+3) $, as, $A$ is diagonalizable, if $0$ has A.M. $k$ ($1\le k \le 5 $), then $-3$ has A.M. is $(6-k)$. Rank of $A$ is $(6-k)$.

For the case, when $p(x)=x(x+3)(x-5) $ , if A.M. of $0$ is $m$,($1\le m \le 4 $), then rank($A$)=$(6-m)$.

I think you can proceed for other cases in similar way.

Comment: My question has four options.  1) 2 . 2)3 . 3)4 . 4)5. What is answer  ? Why ?

Comment: 1st option possible, take , $A=diag(0,0,0,0-3,5) $ or $diag(0,0,0,0,5,5)$ or there are some other forms,,.                 For 2nd option, take $A=diag(0,0,0,-3,5,5)$ or $diag(0,0,0,5,5,5)$ or can be make such form of matrix,.        For 3rd option, take $A=diag(0,0,5,5,5,5)$.                           For option (4), take, $A=diag(0,5,5,5,-3,-3) $.                         All options are true, you creat such many more matrices as you want by seeing cases, what I have included in answer.

Comment: We have $tr(A) =4$ so $ A=diag(0,0,5,5,-3,-3)$ .

Comment: No, the diagonal matrix has $4$ non zero diagonal elements, so, null space of $A$ has dimension $2$, so, rank=$6-2=4$.                          There is no matter of trace!

Comment: For rank = $4$, you can take also , $A=diag(0,0,5,5,5,5) $ or $diag(0,0,-3,-3,-3,-3)$ or $diag(0,0,5,5,5,-3)$ etc.                                        Why this is happening, I already included in my answer, please follow the different form of minimal polynomials, and from them creating possible matrices.

Comment: @devoter please , if you don't understand my answer, it's ok, but it is not a wrong answer, so, before devoting, please assure, don't missuse your power!!!!!